# Use a Byte[] in Image.Source in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a viewModel returning a byte[] image from database and I want to use it on my image.Source

My .XAML

```cs
<Image x:Name="imgPerfil" Aspect="AspectFill" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Image>
```

My .XAML.CS

```cs
public InformacoesUsuario ()
        {           
            InitializeComponent();

            viewModel = new InformacoesUsuarioVM(Login.seq_cliente);
            viewModel.LoadItemsCommand.Execute(null);

            imgPerfil.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(viewModel.Item.foto));
        }
```

I thought that it will work, but not success

Comment: are you **positive** that `foto` contains valid image data?

Comment: i think so, cause the array are filled

Comment: That doesn't mean anything.  It could be filled with garbage data.

Comment: Since you are not using bindings at the moment you call `imgPerfil.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(viewModel.Item.foto));` the image at `viewModel.Item.foto` must be ready to use otherwise you will not get anything. 

I see you are using VM's, change the image Source assignment to Binding (either in code or XAML) and see if that works.

Note: Update your post above with the code for the `InformacoesUsuarioVM` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
imgPerfil.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(viewModel.Item.foto));
```

This will work, but could you do the following:
Debug the byte array as a base64 image:

```
Debug.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(viewModel.Item.foto));
```

Then you could use the output to check if the base64 image is really there by pasting the string in this site:
[Base64 to image](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter)

Comment: I did this but returns no value on Debug.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(viewModel.Item.foto));

Comment: this should output data to the debug console

Comment: Try: Debug.WriteLine("Output:"+Convert.ToBase64String(viewModel.Item.foto)); if the result is only output then the problem is that you don't have any data in the string in the first place.